# extend class from an angularjs 2 library

Tags: angular, typescript

When i try to extend from a class that is in a library based on https://github.com/jhades/angular2-library-example

ie - class in lib:

```
export class Stuff {
    foo: string = "BAR";
}
```

class in my app

```
export class SomeClass extends Stuff {
}
```

---

I always get the following error:

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Class     constructor Stuff cannot be invoked without 'new'
TypeError: Class constructor Stuff cannot be invoked without 'new'
at new HomeComponent (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:46859:16)
at new Wrapper_HomeComponent (/AppModule/HomeComponent/wrapper.ngfactory.js:7:18)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_HomeComponent_Host0.createInternal (/AppModule/HomeComponent/host.ngfactory.js:15:29)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.createHostView (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:58198:21)
at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.createHostView (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:58458:52)
at ComponentFactory.create (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:28964:25)
at ViewContainerRef_.createComponent (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:42370:45)
at RouterOutlet.activate (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:46144:40)
at ActivateRoutes.placeComponentIntoOutlet (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:15248:16)
at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:15222:22)
at http://localhost:3000/main.bundle.js:15177:58
at Array.forEach (native)
```

Comment: Did you include that class ?

Comment: Yes I included it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't extend a component since you won't inherit the metadata of the parent component class.

This article could help you to understand what is the problem:

https://medium.com/@ttemplier/angular2-decorators-and-class-inheritance-905921dbd1b7

Comment: Oh that's odd, it does work when the class in part of the app rather than a library. So this problem only occurs with components and only when the extended class if in a dependency library then ?

Comment: I did, but it doesn't say anything about why it affecting only classes from libraries. Also I've just tested inheriting from a normal class (not a component), and that doesn't work either